# Warning: Dangling Javadoc comment

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc, android-studio-2.3

Since I updated my Android Studio (2.3.1) and build tools (2.3.1), I'm getting warning,

> Warning: Dangling Javadoc comment

for comments like,

```
/** set name with format, {@Link FORMAT_NAME} **/
setNameText(getFormattedName(FORMAT_NAME));
```

As you can see, I use javadoc style comment for linking and others. I'm wondering if there are other comment alternatives that have linking feature.

Thanks.

Comment: comment, you mentioned, should really be regular javadoc comment for that method. This is because, comment describes, what that method is doing, and code comments should describe - why are you calling that method and not other.

Answer (score 29):

In case it helps someone else, make sure you didn't sneak your JavaDoc between the method/class definition and any annotations you had on that definition.

Comment: The IDE ought to provide this as an auto-fix option. Or detect it as a distinct error like "javadoc between attribute and declaration"

Answer (score 25):

It looks like you are using a Javadoc comment when you **call** the method `setNameText`. [Javadoc comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) are to be inserted ***above*** a **class declaration**, a **method declaration**, or a **field declaration**.

If you simply want a comment when calling the method, use the one-line comment: `// get formatted name based on {@link FORMAT_NAME}`.

Comment: but with one-line comment, using {@link FORMAT_NAME} won't link as it does with Javadoc comment. I checked this on Android Studio IDE.

Comment: @Dhunju_likes_to_Learn That may be so, but the fact remains that where you have placed that comment is an incorrect spot for a javadoc comment.

Comment: @nasch, agreed.

Answer (score 21):

You are using Javadoc format which starts with /**  instead of a block comment format which starts with  /* .

To alleviate that warning, always start your comments inside the methods with  /* not  /**.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace "Dangling Javadoc Comment" with block comment.

Comment: Then you cannot use {@link } - that is indexed by IDEs only in javadocs.

Comment: @Ev0oD If u  want to use {@link}, maybe the best choice is disable the "Dangling Javadoc comments" report in the AS's Inspections. Then u can use "Javadoc comments" anywhere, but this is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You may just turn it off in page "File-Settings-Editor-Inspections-Java-Javadoc issues-Dangling Javadoc comment".

Comment: Warnings are there to help improve the quality of your code, you don't just turn them off. There's a reason behind this warning, as other answers explain.

Comment: The only scenario where you might turn off a warning is when you have convincing reasons that the warning is unnecessary which I don't think is the case here. If you really think this warning is unnecessary you should explain your reasons in your answer. Thanks

Comment: @pedram bashiri, could you please point out what is the reason for this warning? The only thing I see wrong about using javadoc comment like this is that it breaks the convention.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like the right place for this comment is alongside method getFormattedName() because your comment explains the functionality of that method not the reason you're calling it.

Comment: I changed the question to reflect what that piece of code does. I took a simple example here but in many cases I need to put a long comment describing what a block of code does. And often I need to use @link to link to other places in code so that it is easier to follow/understand the comment.

Comment: you can use @link in any type of comments. Look at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html "This tag [@link] is valid in all documentation comments: overview, module, package, class, interface, constructor, method and field". This is the right format {@link package.class#member label }

Comment: that would've been perfect! But when I tested using {@link} with one line comment but it doesn't link :( . Also, spec says any type of "documentation" comments.