# Is it possible to write JavaDoc on the same line after declaration in IntelliJ IDEA (Android Studio)?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

I want to be able to declare multiple short javadocs like this:

```
private static int VALUE1 = 1; ///< This is one.
private static int VALUE2 = 2; ///< This is two.
private static int VALUE3 = 3; ///< This is three.
```

I know some tools supports same-line documentation comments like this.
Is it possible in IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio?

Comment: What is the purpose? Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375177/warning-dangling-javadoc-comment

Comment: When declaring a list of similar looking constants/fields, it looks ugly placing comments between them. Such lists looks much better formatted like my sample code shows.

Comment: You can insert the `/* */` block comments at the end of each line with `Ctrl+Shift+/`

Comment: I could insert // single-line comment as well. But it is NOT javadoc I asked for.